# Using openssl in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, openssl

How can I use openssl when accessing data using PHP 5.3?

I hope I can get how to use it. Please give me an example as how to access data using OpenSSL.

Comment: If your PHP app is a website; you can just use `https://yourwebsite.com` (note the S on HTTP)

Comment: I think this post is a duplicate to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176367/openssl-php-how-to-implement-it

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to generate a pair of keys with php?

```
$NEW_KEY = openssl_pkey_new(array(
    'private_key_bits' => 1024,
    'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
        ));

openssl_pkey_export_to_file($NEW_KEY, 'private.key');

$NEW_KEY_DETAILS = openssl_pkey_get_details($NEW_KEY);
file_put_contents('public.key', $NEW_KEY_DETAILS['key']);

openssl_free_key($NEW_KEY);
```

Do you already have the keys ?

```
$public = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDfmlc2EgrdhvakQApmLCDOgP0n
NERInBheMh7J/r5aU8PUAIpGXET/8+kOGI1dSYjoux80AuHvkWp1EeHfMwC/SZ9t
6rF4sYqV5Lj9t32ELbh2VNbE/7QEVZnXRi5GdhozBZtS1gJHM2/Q+iToyh5dfTaA
U8bTnLEPMNC1h3qcUQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

$private = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

if (!$privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($private)) die('Loading Private Key failed');
if (!$publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_public($public)) die('Loading Public Key failed');

$encrypted = '';
$decrypted = '';

$plaintext = 'This is just some text to encrypt';

echo '<p>$plaintext = ' . $plaintext . '<p>';

if (!openssl_public_encrypt($plaintext, $encrypted, $publicKey))    die('Failed to encrypt data');

echo '<p>$encrypted = ' . $encrypted . '<p>';

if (!openssl_private_decrypt($encrypted, $decrypted, $privateKey))  die('Failed to decrypt data');

echo '<p>$decrypted = ' . $decrypted . '<p>';
```

There you go, Enjoy!

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176367